# Google Cloud build error "print_env_info.py: error: unrecognized arguments"

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to get a Google Cloud development environment up and running on my Windows (64 bit) computer.

I followed instructions for Java at https://console.developers.google.com/start/appengine on my Windows computer but on step 6 ("Create Your Project and Deploy") I got this error message:

> D:\google-app-engine\appengine-try-java>appcfg.cmd -A
>   midyear-tempo-554 update t arget\appengine-try-java usage:
>   print_env_info.py [-h] item print_env_info.py: error: unrecognized
>   arguments: Osofsky\AppData\Roaming\gcloud \tmp-env-info-10521.txt

I was able to complete all the other steps.  The only anomaly was in Step 4 ("Run Your App Locally") where I got the following error when I tried to run install.bat:

> To use the Google Cloud SDK, you must have Python installed and on
>   your PATH. As an alternative, you may also set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON
>   environment variable to the location of your Python executable.

I successfully solved this problem by adding the following line to install.bat:

```
set CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=C:\Python27\python.exe
```

I wasn't sure if this caused `"print_env_info.py: error: unrecognized arguments"`, but it seems related because they both have to do with environment variables.  So I added `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=C:\Python27\python.exe` to my user-level environment variables.  I then started a new command prompt, confirmed via a `"set"` command that `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=C:\Python27\python.exe` had registered, and tried again but I still got this error:

> D:\google-app-engine\appengine-try-java>appcfg.cmd -A
>   midyear-tempo-554 update t arget\appengine-try-java usage:
>   print_env_info.py [-h] item print_env_info.py: error: unrecognized
>   arguments: Osofsky\AppData\Roaming\gcloud \tmp-env-info-8445.txt

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A representative from Google Enterprise Support named Jordan gave me the revised appcfg.cmd file below.  It helped get me past the error I was having.  Unfortunately there's another issue now, but I think the solution below addresses the original error I posted about.  Thanks Heeryu and Tatiana for your offers of help.

```
@echo off 

rem Copyright 2013 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. 



cmd /c "python "%~dp0bootstrapping\prerun.py" --command-name=appcfg-java --component-id=gae-java --check-credentials --check-updates" 

IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ( 

EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL% 

) 



SETLOCAL 



set TMPFILE=%APPDATA%\gcloud\tmp-env-info-%RANDOM%.txt 



cmd /c "python "%~dp0bootstrapping\print_env_info.py" gae_java_path > "%TMPFILE%" 

IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ( 

EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL% 

) 



set /p credential_path= < "%TMPFILE%" 

del "%TMPFILE%"



cmd /c ""%~dp0..\platform/appengine-java-sdk\bin\appcfg.cmd" --oauth2 --oauth2_config_file="%credential_path%" %*" 

IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ( 

EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL% 

) 



ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: In my answer above I said "unfortunately there's another issue now" which was solved by this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23303685/google-cloud-appcfg-cmd-cant-deploy-because-cant-find-appengine-web-xml

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be the space in the directory name, where it tries to print temporary file.
Work around steps that solved this problem for me:

1) Create some new empty directory with no spaces in the path, for example, `D:\google-cloud-sdk\tmp`

2) Modify `D:\google-cloud-sdk\bin\appcfg.cmd` file by replacing `%APPDATA%\gcloud\` with your 
newly created directory path `D:\google-cloud-sdk\tmp\`